How to block specific GNSS constellations or sattelites from being used to calculate a location
In order to test some theories I need the gps chip in an android phone to calculate the geographic location while using only certain gnss constellations or sattelites.
For example using only GPS and Galileo sattelite signals and ignoring Beidou and Glonass signals. The used constellations for the calculation needs to be configurable.
In later development I would like to be able to use that data as the location source for other applications on the phone.
The app can target new phones and new Android versions.
I tried looking into the new api of the android location services and other open source solutions but was unable to find a good example or working open source app or library.
Any good leads or recommendations?
